# parse.com, where does parseSendRequest() show up on ParseIot dashboard

Tags: parse-platform

I am writing a small sensor send Request from 'C' on Raspberry Pi to the parseIoT platform from this link

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/raspberrypi

Where does this show up on the Parse Dashboard ?
I was hoping to see it in Data 
Modified Sample code from main.c is :

strcpy (data , " '{ \'currentTemperature\': 175.0 }'");

parseSendRequest(client, "POST", "/1/classes/TemperatureReading", data, NULL);

Answer (score 0):

`parseSendRequest()` is a helper method for creating HTTP requests against Parse's REST API. In this specific case, you're making a POST call to the `/1/classes/TemperatureReading` endpoint with a  JSON payload of `{ "currentTemperature": 175.0 }`. This will effectively create a new "TemperatureReading" object with a "currentTemperature" Number key value of 175.0.

You can confirm this by visiting your Data Browser (See Data) within the Parse Dashboard.

To understand how this request ended up creating a new object, I suggest reading the [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest) Guide.